# Is there a shorter way to create loops trough the rows when using append?

Tags: python, append, multiple-columns

I have a data frame with employees and all the roles that they are able to do.

`

```
    Employees   ID  Brand_Manager   Payroll_Manager Accountant  Auditor
0   Jessi           1A         1           0           1      0
1   Lara            1B         1           0           0      1
2   Mike            1C         1           0           0          0
3   Artur           1D         1           0           0      0
4   James           2A         1           0           0      0
5   Claudia         3B         1           0           0          0
6   Zuzska          4C         1           1           0          1
7   Bartz           2B         1           1           0      0
8   Alexa           3B         1           1           0      0
```

`

To make work the program that I want to apply, I need to split the data and create new rows for the same person for each role (value=1). The rest of the values for the rest of the roles will become 0.
The codes work well when using append(), however this example contain only 8 employees and 4 roles. I need to do the same with a lot more employees and almost 100 extra roles, which will create a very long script.

I have done this:
First, select all the employees that have more than one role

```
col_list=df.columns
df['many'] = df[col_list].sum(axis=1)
df_single   =  df[ df['many'] == 1  ]
df_many    =  df[ df['many'] >= 2  ]
```

Then create lists and append:

```
lststaff = list ( df_many.Employees)

lstEmployees = []
lstID = []
lstBrand_Manager = []
lstPayroll_Manager = []
lstAccountant = []
lstAuditor = []
```

Loop through the names

```
for i in lststaff:


  ID = str ( df_many.loc [ df_many['Employees'] == i, 'ID' ].tolist()[0] ) 


  Brand_Manager = ( df_many.loc [ df_many['Employees'] == i, 'Brand_Manager'].astype(int) )
  Brand_Manager = np.array(Brand_Manager)
  if ( Brand_Manager == 1 ).any():  
      lstEmployees.append ( i + '_Brand_Manager'  )
      lstAccountant.append (0)
      lstBrand_Manager.append(1)
      lstAuditor.append(0)
      lstID.append (ID)
      lstPayroll_Manager.append(0)
  
    
  Accountant = ( df_many.loc [ df_many['Employees'] == i, 'Accountant'].astype(int) )
  Accountant = np.array(Accountant)
  if ( Accountant == 1 ).any():  
      lstEmployees.append ( i + '_Accountant'  )
      lstAccountant.append (1)
      lstBrand_Manager.append(0)
      lstAuditor.append(0)
      lstID.append (ID)
      lstPayroll_Manager.append(0)
    
  Auditor = ( df_many.loc [ df_many['Employees'] == i, 'Auditor'].astype(int) )
  Auditor = np.array(Auditor)
  if ( Auditor == 1 ).any():  
      lstEmployees.append ( i + '_Auditor' )
      lstAccountant.append (0)
      lstBrand_Manager.append(0)
      lstAuditor.append(1)
      lstID.append (ID)
      lstPayroll_Manager.append(0)
    
  Payroll_Manager = ( df_many.loc [ df_many['Employees'] == i, 'Payroll_Manager'].astype(int) )
  Payroll_Manager = np.array(Payroll_Manager)
  if ( Payroll_Manager == 1 ).any():  
      lstEmployees.append ( i + '_Payroll_Manager'  )
      lstAccountant.append (0)
      lstBrand_Manager.append(0)
      lstAuditor.append(0)
      lstID.append (ID)
      lstPayroll_Manager.append(1)
    


final_df = pd.DataFrame ( {
   "Employees"  : lstEmployees
   ,"ID"   : lstID
   ,"Brand_Manager" :lstBrand_Manager
   ,"Accountant" :lstAccountant
   ,"Auditor" : lstAuditor
   ,"Payroll_Manager" : lstPayroll_Manager 
}
)

final_df
```

The codes works well, however if I have to add 100 more roles. I will add 100 more lists and the amount of lists to be appended would be crazy.... Is there any other way of doing it with a function or for loops?

The output is as follow:

```
    Employees   ID  Brand_Manager   Accountant  Auditor Payroll_Manager
0   Jessi_Brand_Manager 1A  1   0   0   0
1   Jessi_Accountant    1A  0   1   0   0
2   Lara_Brand_Manager  1B  1   0   0   0
3   Lara_Auditor    1B  0   0   1   0
4   Zuzska_Brand_Manager    4C  1   0   0   0
5   Zuzska_Auditor  4C  0   0   1   0
6   Zuzska_Payroll_Manager  4C  0   0   0   1
7   Bartz_Brand_Manager 2B  1   0   0   0
8   Bartz_Payroll_Manager   2B  0   0   0   1
9   Alexa_Brand_Manager 3B  1   0   0   0
10  Alexa_Payroll_Manager   3B  0   0   0   1
```

Comment: Edit the format of your question, separating code and descriptions. Anyway why not use a list for columns(roles) and a 2D list(list of lists) for flags(0/1)? Start with ```roles = list(df.columns[2:]); list_of_flags = []``` and implement a nested loops, for the ```lststaff``` and ```roles```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach. `pandas` gives a "SettingWithCopy" warning, but I believe this script will always result in the expected behavior.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#input dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Employees': {0: 'Jessi', 1: 'Lara', 2: 'Mike', 3: 'Artur', 4: 'James', 5: 'Claudia', 6: 'Zuzska', 7: 'Bartz', 8: 'Alexa'}, 'ID': {0: '1A', 1: '1B', 2: '1C', 3: '1D', 4: '2A', 5: '3B', 6: '4C', 7: '2B', 8: '3B'}, 'Brand_Manager': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}, 'Payroll_Manager': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1}, 'Accountant': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0}, 'Auditor': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 1, 7: 0, 8: 0}})

# isolate job columns
job_cols = df.columns.drop(['Employees','ID'])
num_jobs = len(job_cols)

# drop employees with only one job
df_in = df.loc[df[job_cols].sum(axis = 1)>=2,:]

# information processing
def get_nums(row):
    return np.eye(num_jobs, dtype = int)[row.astype(bool)]
def get_labels(row):
    return job_cols[row.astype(bool)]

df_proc = df_in[['Employees','ID']]
df_proc.loc[:,'all'] = df_in[job_cols].apply(get_nums,axis = 1)
df_proc = df_proc.explode('all').reset_index(drop=True)
df_proc[job_cols] = np.vstack(df_proc['all'])
df_proc['jobs'] = df_in[job_cols].apply(get_labels,axis = 1).explode().reset_index(drop=True)

# generate output dataframe
df_out = df_proc[['Employees','ID',*job_cols]]
df_out.loc[:,'Employees'] = df_proc['Employees'] + '_' + df_proc['jobs']
```

Resulting dataframe `df_out`:

```
                 Employees  ID  Brand_Manager  Payroll_Manager  Accountant  \
0      Jessi_Brand_Manager  1A              1                0           0   
1         Jessi_Accountant  1A              0                0           1   
2       Lara_Brand_Manager  1B              1                0           0   
3             Lara_Auditor  1B              0                0           0   
4     Zuzska_Brand_Manager  4C              1                0           0   
5   Zuzska_Payroll_Manager  4C              0                1           0   
6           Zuzska_Auditor  4C              0                0           0   
7      Bartz_Brand_Manager  2B              1                0           0   
8    Bartz_Payroll_Manager  2B              0                1           0   
9      Alexa_Brand_Manager  3B              1                0           0   
10   Alexa_Payroll_Manager  3B              0                1           0   

    Auditor  
0         0  
1         0  
2         0  
3         1  
4         0  
5         0  
6         1  
7         0  
8         0  
9         0  
10        0
```

Intermediate dataframe df_proc before generating df_out, for reference:

```
   Employees  ID           all  Brand_Manager  Payroll_Manager  Accountant  \
0      Jessi  1A  [1, 0, 0, 0]              1                0           0   
1      Jessi  1A  [0, 0, 1, 0]              0                0           1   
2       Lara  1B  [1, 0, 0, 0]              1                0           0   
3       Lara  1B  [0, 0, 0, 1]              0                0           0   
4     Zuzska  4C  [1, 0, 0, 0]              1                0           0   
5     Zuzska  4C  [0, 1, 0, 0]              0                1           0   
6     Zuzska  4C  [0, 0, 0, 1]              0                0           0   
7      Bartz  2B  [1, 0, 0, 0]              1                0           0   
8      Bartz  2B  [0, 1, 0, 0]              0                1           0   
9      Alexa  3B  [1, 0, 0, 0]              1                0           0   
10     Alexa  3B  [0, 1, 0, 0]              0                1           0   

    Auditor             jobs  
0         0    Brand_Manager  
1         0       Accountant  
2         0    Brand_Manager  
3         1          Auditor  
4         0    Brand_Manager  
5         0  Payroll_Manager  
6         1          Auditor  
7         0    Brand_Manager  
8         0  Payroll_Manager  
9         0    Brand_Manager  
10        0  Payroll_Manager
```

Comment: Hi, That is exactly what I am looking for. However, it seems that the code does not work for me as it gives me a 'Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional' when running the 'df_proc.loc[:,'all'] = df_in[job_cols].apply(get_nums,axis = 1)'. I have been trying to understand why it does not work for me but I cannot find the answer.

Comment: @Mike That's bizarre; I did whether it would work with a simple copy and paste. Try to figure out which version of python you're using and which version of pandas you have, and let me know.

Comment: @Mike Try changing the one line of the get_nums function into `return np.eye(num_jobs, dtype = int)[row.astype(bool)].tolist()`

Comment: @Mike For me, `print(pd.__version__)` gives 1.3.5; the latest stable release is 1.5.1. What do you get?

Comment: Yes, adding the tolist() makes the code work. If I print the pd. version I get 0.20.3. I think this might be the problem as more errors keep coming like ''DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode''. I have read these both issues might be because of the pandas or environment version, I have update it but I can see it is not reading it

Comment: @Mike I definitely recommend that you update your python distribution, then

Comment: Everything working perfect now, just needed to update the python as you said. Very helpful. I really appreciate it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Mike Glad to hear it! You're welcome